# My MSACCESS QRY stoped working after I added and Autonumber Field and changed two text fields to Integer

Tags: ms-access, vb6, ado

I've been working with this MSACCESS Qry and it used to work fine:

```
Qry = "UPDATE Inv_Products " _
& "SET Nombre    = '" & txtFields(1).Text & "'" _
& ", Descripción = '" & txtFields(2).Text & "'" _
& ", UDMC        = '" & txtFields(4).Text & "'" _
& ", UDMV        = '" & txtFields(5).Text & "'" _
& ", Min         = '" & txtFields(6).Text & "'" _
& ", Max         = '" & txtFields(7).Text & "'" _
& ", Gross       = '" & txtFields(8).Text & "'" _
& ", Costo       = '" & txtFields(9).Text & "'" _
& ", Compra      = '" & txtFields(10).Text & "'" _
& ", Maquila     = '" & txtFields(11).Text & "'" _
& ", Venta       = '" & txtFields(12).Text & "'" _
& ", Público     = '" & txtFields(13).Text & "'" _
& ", Insumo      = '" & chkChecks(0).Value & "'" _
& ", Srv         = '" & chkChecks(1).Value & "'" _
& ", Refacción   = '" & chkChecks(5).Value & "'" _
& ", Línea       = '" & txtFields(14).Text & "' " _
& ", Marca       = '" & txtFields(15).Text & "' " _
& "WHERE ProdId  = '" & txtFields(0).Text & "' "
```

Now I have been trying with these and combinations, but still nothing:

```
Qry = "UPDATE Inv_Products " _
& "SET Nombre    = '" & txtFields(1).Text & "'" _
& ", Descripción = '" & txtFields(2).Text & "'" _
& ", UDMC        = '" & txtFields(4).Text & "'" _
& ", UDMV        = '" & txtFields(5).Text & "'" _
& ", Min         = '" & CDbl(txtFields(6).Text) & "'" _
& ", Max         = '" & CDbl(txtFields(7).Text) & "'" _
& ", Gross       = '" & CCur(txtFields(8).Text) & "'" _
& ", Costo       = '" & CCur(txtFields(9).Text) & "'" _
& ", Compra      = '" & CCur(txtFields(10).Text) & "'" _
& ", Maquila     = '" & CCur(txtFields(11).Text) & "'" _
& ", Venta       = '" & CCur(txtFields(12).Text) & "'" _
& ", Público     = '" & CCur(txtFields(13).Text) & "'" _
& ", Insumo      = '" & CInt(chkChecks(0).Value) & "'" _
& ", Srv         = '" & CInt(chkChecks(1).Value) & "'" _
& ", Refacción   = '" & CInt(chkChecks(5).Value) & "'" _
& ", Línea       = '" & CInt(txtFields(14).Text) & "' " _
& ", Marca       = '" & CInt(txtFields(15).Text) & "' " _
& "WHERE ProdId  = '" & txtFields(0).Text & "' "
```

It keeps saying "Syntax Error"
In my table I have and Autonumber ID and ccur are defined as currency, cint long integer and cdbl are declared as double.

What I did different was I added and ID field with auto number and changed Lénea and Marca as Integer because they are related to the Autonumber ID on another table.

If I use data grid with edit and addnew enabled it works fine...

```
Set ADOPrdctsRs = New adodb.Recordset
ADOPrdctsRs.Open "SELECT ID, ProdID, Nombre, Descripción, " _
& "UDMC, UDMV, Min, Max, Gross, Costo, Compra, Maquila, Venta, Público, " _
& "Línea, Marca, Insumo, Srv, Refacción " _
& "FROM Inv_Products " _
& "ORDER BY Descripción", Chazaro, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

Set grdDataGrid.DataSource = ADOPrdctsRs
```

But in textboxes won't work, I even tried binding them.

Any advice on what to look for?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I do not know why and how. But it is working this way.

```
                With ADOPrdctsRs.Fields
                !Nombre = txtFields(1).Text
                !Descripción = txtFields(2).Text
                !UDMC = txtFields(4).Text
                !UDMV = txtFields(5).Text
                !Min = CDbl(txtFields(6).Text)
                !Max = CDbl(txtFields(7).Text)
                !Gross = CCur(txtFields(8).Text)
                !Costo = CCur(txtFields(9).Text)
                !Compra = CCur(txtFields(10).Text)
                !Maquila = CCur(txtFields(11).Text)
                !Venta = CCur(txtFields(12).Text)
                !Público = CCur(txtFields(13).Text)
                !Insumo = CInt(chkChecks(0).Value)
                !Srv = CInt(chkChecks(1).Value)
                !Refacción = CInt(chkChecks(5).Value)
                !Línea = CInt(txtFields(14).Text)
                !Marca = CInt(txtFields(15).Text)
            End With
            ADOPrdctsRs.Update
```

I mean, I know, but it should have worked the other way...

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Make it a habit to use [parameterized queries](https://riptutorial.com/vba/example/12354/creating-parameterized-commands) for your database inserts/updates. This handles the necessary type conversion and escaping for you and also protects you from [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use single-quotes for numeric fields, and force the decimal separator to a dot:

```vb
Qry = "UPDATE Inv_Products " _
& "SET Nombre    = '" & txtFields(1).Text & "'" _
& ", Descripción = '" & txtFields(2).Text & "'" _
& ", UDMC        = '" & txtFields(4).Text & "'" _
& ", UDMV        = '" & txtFields(5).Text & "'" _
& ", Min         = " & Str(CDbl(txtFields(6).Text)) & "" _
& ", Max         = " & Str(CDbl(txtFields(7).Text)) & "" _
& ", Gross       = " & Str(CCur(txtFields(8).Text)) & "" _
& ", Costo       = " & Str(CCur(txtFields(9).Text)) & "" _
& ", Compra      = " & Str(CCur(txtFields(10).Text)) & "" _
& ", Maquila     = " & Str(CCur(txtFields(11).Text)) & "" _
& ", Venta       = " & Str(CCur(txtFields(12).Text)) & "" _
& ", Público     = " & Str(CCur(txtFields(13).Text)) & "" _
& ", Insumo      = " & Str(CInt(chkChecks(0).Value)) & "" _
& ", Srv         = " & Str(CInt(chkChecks(1).Value)) & "" _
& ", Refacción   = " & Str(CInt(chkChecks(5).Value)) & "" _
& ", Línea       = " & Str(CInt(txtFields(14).Text)) & "" _
& ", Marca       = " & Str(CInt(txtFields(15).Text)) & "" _
& "WHERE ProdId  = '" & txtFields(0).Text & "'"
```

Comment: I still am getting the syntax error... I also tried without str, same result.. I'll try using the main recordset directly. And let you know. Thank you

Comment: Print the finished `Qry` and it will be clear to you.